# Where do the "semantics" of a Bayesian network come from?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-networks, graphical-model

On Bayesian Networks, Ghahramani (2001) says:

> A node is independent of its non-descendants given its parents.

This point is fundamental enough that Ghahramani calls it the “semantics” of a Bayesian network.  It is certainly useful, and it is simple enough to prove using d-separation.  But his characterization suggests that the property should be even more primitive than something provable by d-separation.

Overall, I feel that I am missing something.   Is there a more primitive way to verify the statement than to use d-separation?  Why does Gharamani equate that fact specifically to the semantics of a Bayesian network, rather than equating the semantics to the overall conditional independencies in the network (given by d-separation)? And if the statement is a consequence of d-separation, why focus on this fact specifically rather than the (arguably equally useful) fact about Markov blankets?

Reference: Ghahramani, Z. (2001). An introduction to hidden Markov models and Bayesian networks. In Hidden Markov models: applications in computer vision (pp. 9-41).

Comment: Maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this question?

Comment: Yes, perhaps.   I think it's generally unclear where to ask machine learning questions.

Comment: Is it kosher to re-post the exact same question there, while leaving it up here?  Or should I follow some other process?

Comment: I think it's fine, otherwise you can flag your own question and ask a moderator to migrate it properly (it might take longer, I don't know). Your question fits on both sites, I recommended CrossValidatedSE mostly because there are more contributors there, so you'd have a better chance to get a good answer.